# angular pipe can not be rendered on the locallhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular

i am learnig how to use pipes in Angular and i follow the directions and guidance stated in the following tutorial:

```
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pipes/
```

the problem i am facing is, that when i run

```
ng serve --open
```

i do not see the text specified in templateUrl which is shown below in the code.

what i get id the page shown below
please let me know why the html can not be rendered

**app.component.ts**:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: `<p> Unformatted date : {{toDate }} </p>
                  <p> Formatted date : {{toDate | date}} </p>` 
}) 
export class AppComponent 
{ 
    title: string = 'pipe Example' ; 
    toDate: Date = new Date(); 
}
```

**update**:

i tried also the following but it did not work

```
**app.component.ts**:

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html' 
    }) 
    export class AppComponent 
    { 
        title: string = 'pipe Example' ; 
        toDate: Date = new Date(); 
    }

    
**app.component.html**:

    <p> Unformatted date : {{toDate }} </p>
    <p> Formatted date : {{toDate | date}} </p>
```

**image**:

[image]

Comment: can you create a stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `templateUrl` property to `template`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<p> Unformatted date : {{ toDate }} </p>
             <p> Formatted date : {{ toDate | date}} </p>` 
})
```

Comment: still it does not work...please see the update in my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign value like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        template: `<p> Unformatted date : {{toDate }} </p>
                      <p> Formatted date : {{toDate | date}} </p>` 
    }) 
    export class AppComponent 
    { 
        title: string = 'pipe Example' ; 
        toDate: Date = new Date(); 
    }
        }
```

Comment: still it does not work...please see the update in my question

Answer (score 0):

Replace `templateUrl` with `template`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<p> Unformatted date : {{toDate }} </p>
                  <p> Formatted date : {{toDate | date}} </p>` 
}) 
export class AppComponent { 
    title: string = 'pipe Example' ; 
    toDate: Date = new Date(); 
}
```

https://devconquer.com/angular/template-vs-templateurl/

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zefd2f?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @amrmbso01 Check the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zefd2f?file=src/app/app.component.ts) and see what you made wrong.